# infinite loop over divs showing 4 at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create something akin to a slide show, whenever the button `#more-projects`is clicked 4 divs would show, when it's clicked again those divs get hidden and the next 4 divs show, this needs to loop infinitely and be applied to any number of divs.

In this context I have 6 divs with the class `.thumbnail-cnt` within the div '#container', when I click `#more-projects` I would like the first 4 of these divs to show, divs 1,2,3,4. When `#more-projects` is clicked again the next 4 divs in the cycle would be shown so 5,6,1,2. Clicked again, divs 1,2,3,4 are shown. How can I select the next index and make the function iterate over the elements infinitely?

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="1">1
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="2">2
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="3">3
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="4">4
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="5">5
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="6">6
    </div>
</div>

<button id="more-projects" > Next
</button>
```

My JS so far is

```
var startIndex = 0;

$('#more-projects').on("click", function() {
    var endIndex = startIndex + 4;
    var nextIndex = endIndex +1;
    $('#container .thumbnail-cnt').slice(startIndex, endIndex).addClass('visible');
    var startIndex = nextIndex;
}
```

CSS

```
.thumbnail-cnt {
    display: none;
}
.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: How will you be determining the amount of `divs` shown on screen?

Comment: They will be outputted through a CMS

Comment: What server side language are you using? Not that it entirely matters, but it can help me structure a more relevant answer for you.

Comment: Thank for replying. I'm using PHP, the CMS is [Kirby](https://getkirby.com/docs/)

Comment: Ok, I will add an answer below, one moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution can be based on:

- save the initial value of max  number of visible items as data value of your div
- save the start index as another data value

So, the initial value is:

```
<div id="container" data-start-index="0" data-max-visible-length="4">
```

In the click handler compute the end index position. If it exceeds the max you need to start from the beginning. Save this new value as the new start index.

```js
$('#more-projects').on("click", function() {
    var startIndex = $('#container').data('startIndex');
    var maxVisibleLength = $('#container').data('maxVisibleLength');
    var endIndex = startIndex + maxVisibleLength;
    var itemCounts = $('#container .thumbnail-cnt').length;
    $('#container .thumbnail-cnt.visible').removeClass('visible');
    if (endIndex > itemCounts) {
        endIndex = endIndex - itemCounts;
        $('#container .thumbnail-cnt').slice(startIndex).addClass('visible');
        $('#container .thumbnail-cnt').slice(0, endIndex).addClass('visible');
    } else {
        $('#container .thumbnail-cnt').slice(startIndex, endIndex).addClass('visible');
    }
    $('#container').data('startIndex', endIndex);
});
```

```css
.thumbnail-cnt {
    display: none;
}
.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="container" data-start-index="0" data-max-visible-length="4">
    <div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="1">1
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="2">2
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="3">3
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="4">4
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="5">5
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="6">6
    </div>
</div>

<button id="more-projects" > Next
</button>
```

Comment: This is a fantastic approach. Thank you for taking the time to help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for your JS. This will ensure an infinite loop-

```
var startIndex = 0;
$('#more-projects').on("click", function() {

var count = 0;    
var divs = $('#container .thumbnail-cnt');
var len = divs.length
var index;
while( count < 4 ){
    index = (startIndex+count) % len; 
    divs[index].addClass('visible');
    count++;
}
startIndex += count;

index++; //to ensure removal start from the next

while( count < len ){
    index = index % len;
    divs[index++].removeClass('visible');
    count++;
}

}
```

`%` ensures the boundary and wrapping. Removing class `visible` for the other divs that need not be shown. Your current implementation must have been failing on this.